# How to get all data below an excel cell

Tags: vb.net, excel, vba

I'm using VB.NET on VB 2017

I want to retrieve a range from an excel spreadsheet.

Somewhere in the sheet, there is a cell with a name "latitude", and on cells under that cell, there is an undetermined number of latitude numbers.

[image: https://i.imgur.com/qslVuHt.jpg]

I find the location of the cell containing the "latitude" string with this code:

```
Dim LatitudeCell = ExcelWorksheet.Cells.Find("latitude")
```

I don't know how to get the range with all the numbers below that cell, since I don't know how many rows contain data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim LastCell as Range
Dim FullRange as Range

Set LastCell = LatitudeCell.End(xlDown)
Set FullRange = Range(LatitudeCell.Offset(1,0), LastCell)
```

That is the code in VBA. It will be the same for VB.Net except that the enumerator xlDown may need to be qualified according to the .Net library.

In VB.NET is

```
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop

Dim LastCell As Excel.Range
Dim FullRange As Excel.Range

LastCell = LatitudeCell.End(Excel.XlDirection.xlDown)
FullRange = ExcelWorksheet.Range(LatitudeCell.Offset(1, 0), LastCell)
```